# django 2. Автоматическое удаление кэша thumbnail

Tags: python, django

Я использую sorl thumbnail из шаблона проекта вот так:

```html
{% thumbnail user.profile.photo "150x150" crop="0%" format="PNG" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

После загрузки изображения, thumbnail обрабатывает его и помещает в директорию media/cache. Есть ли такой способ, чтобы после загрузки нового изображения, старое(которое не используется больше) автоматически удалялось ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то в [документации](https://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/management.html#thumbnail-cleanup) как раз описывается способ удалить кэш при помощи **Management commands**:

**thumbnail cleanup**

```
python manage.py thumbnail cleanup
```

> This cleans up the Key Value Store from stale cache. It removes
>   references to images that do not exist and thumbnail references and
>   their actual files for images that do not exist. It removes thumbnails
>   for unknown images.

Вы ищите автоматический способ, и я думаю, что он не предусмотрен.
Я вижу два пути решения:

1. Вызывать команду `python manage.py thumbnail cleanup` раз в определённое время, используя `cron`:

`*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python python manage.py thumbnail cleanup`

2. В модели с изображением переопределить, скажем, метод `save`, и при каждом его вызове проверять, изменилось ли значение в поле изображения, и если да, то вручную удалить старое изображение:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import delete

# Удаляет Ключ Значение в хранилище, но **не** удаляет сам файл
# Используйте если изменили изображение
delete(my_file, delete_file=False)

# Удаляет Ключ Значение в хранилище, а так же сам файл
# Используйте если хотите удалить файл
delete(my_file) # delete_file=True is default
```

Comment: Вызывал команду python manage.py thumbnail cleanup, неиспользуемые изображения удалились, но папки от них остались, как от них избавляться ?